# Is it possible to read SMS headers?

Tags: sms

Is there a way on Android (I've got Samsung Galaxy S3) to read SMS message headers? If yes,  how can I do this?

Comment: This question has been asked in StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298088/is-it-possilbe-to-read-and-or-modify-the-sms-header-on-android

Comment: I asked not about code. I asked about application, which can make it.